# Using PyWinAuto to control a currently running application

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto, com-object

Using the following code I can find that the currently running window I want to connect is named "Trade Monitor" how do i successfull connect to it? Using the app.start_ method does not work.

```
from pywinauto import application
app=application.Application
app.findwindows #prints all windows running on machine

app.window("Trade Monitor") #error
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `app = Application().connect(title='Trade Monitor', timeout=10)`.
More detailed info is [in the docs here](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html#how-to-specify-a-usable-application-instance).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ended up here, the connect method @Vasily Ryabov mentioned works for PIDs too. Double Thanks to him as the docs he linked explain that.

```py
app = Application().connect(process=1234, timeout=5)
```